# designing models in django-viewflow

Tags: django-viewflow

I am new to django-viewflow and still going through the viewflow related documents including cook-book examples.

In the project that I am working on, I have below models.

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    prod_ref_num = models.IntegerField()
    prod_part_num = models.IntegerField()
```

The above model FirstModel is being updated by external process

```
class SecondModel(models.Model):
     prod_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     prod_category = models.CharField(max_length=30)         
     approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The above model SecondModel is part of the work flow which is mentioned as below).

1. During start of the flow, it should allow to take inputs for prod_type and prod_category and it should execute SQL query (for external data source) using data entered for prod_type and prod_category. The query result should be presented for the user using django_tables2). Based on the query result, user can proceed or cancel the flow.
2. If proceed, it transitions to approval flow.
3. If cancel, data shouldnt get inserted into model Product2.

Can you please provide insights on how the models can be designed in django-viewflow ?

Also how the work flow process can be implemented especially executing SQL and  diplaying query results using django_tables2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewflow provides the workflow layer on top of django views, extracts flow logic, and allows to keep view code independent from the flow.

You can design your django views and models, as usual, just implement them as independent steps, use @flow_view decorator to initialize `request.actiovation` and call `activation.done()` as soon as a task complete.

You can keep your models separated from the viewflow process model, just put a foreign key in a process model to your model.

You can check the shipment demo, for the sample.

https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/demo/shipment/models.py#L63

Comment: Thank You So Much for the details. I tried keeping the models separated from the viewflow process model, however I stumbled at the below error message -

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 625, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'entitlement.Entitlement' cannot be resolved

Comment: Here are my model and viewflow process model ---------------------                                                                          class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    field2 = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    field3 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=60, default=None)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    approved_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True) -----------------
   
class MyProcess(Process):
    mymodel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: -------------- class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MyProcess',
            fields=[
                ('process_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, serialize=False, parent_link=True, to='viewflow.Process', primary_key=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE)),
                ('mymodel', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, to='mymodel.MyModel', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE)),
            ],

Comment: options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
            bases=('viewflow.process',),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MyModel',

Comment: fields=[
                ('field1', models.IntegerField(default=None)),
                ('field2', models.IntegerField(default=None)),
                ('field3', models.CharField(null=True, max_length=60)),
                ('approved', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('approved_at', models.DateTimeField(null=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
]

Comment: In the above post, corrections to error message - File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 625, in resolve_related_fields raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model) ValueError: Related model 'mymodel.MyModel' cannot be resolved

Comment: correction in the error message is to replace the word 'entitlement'/'Entitlement' with 'mymode'l/'MyModel'