# Django-viewflow - keeping models separate from process flow

Tags: django-viewflow

This question is triggered from [designing models in django-viewflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041907/designing-models-in-django-viewflow)

While keeping the models separate from viewflow process, getting the below error -

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 625, in resolve_related_fields raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model) ValueError: Related model'mymodel.MyModel' cannot be resolved
```

Here are my model and viewflow process model class

```
MyModel(models.Model): 
   field1 = models.IntegerField(default=None) 
   field2 = models.IntegerField(default=None) 
   field3 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=60, default=None) 
   approved = models.BooleanField(default=False) approved_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Comment: class MyProcess(Process): mymodel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: class Migration(migrations.Migration): operations = [ migrations.CreateModel( name='MyProcess', fields=[ ('process_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, serialize=False, parent_link=True, to='viewflow.Process', primary_key=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE)), ('mymodel', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, to='mymodel.MyModel', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE)), ],

Comment: Please do not add information to your post via comments; edit the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

Created a separate migration script (appname_initial_01.py)  containing details of 'mymodel' and refer this in dependencies list of migration script (appname_initial_02.py) containing 'MyProcess' resolved the issue.

```
dependencies = [
    ('appname', 'appname_initial_01'),
]
```